# Crystal Reports phone numer

Tags: crystal-reports, formatting

I'm working in a crystal report and need to format a phone number field. The data I am working with is somewhat messed up and there are some numbers formatted correctly

(111)111-1111

and some 1111111111

I'm trying to write this formula that will remove the parentheses and re-format the string. Here's what I have so far and have no clue why this won't work

```
StringVar phone = Replace({AssessorTrainingReport;1.Phone1},"(",""); 
phone := Replace({AssessorTrainingReport;1.Phone1},")","");
Picture (CStr (phone), "(xxx) xxx-xxxx");
```

Comment: What is the expected output? You want to format the first string into the second or the other way?

Answer (score 2):

The second replace call should operate on the stringvar result from the first replace call...

```
phone := Replace(phone,")","");
```

also, do you need to remove the `-` too?

Comment: I tried doing that, too actually and nothing showed up for me. I ended up using the sql replace on the field I was pulling in my stored procedure and that fixed it.

    replace(replace(replace(cj.Phone1, '-', ''),'(',''),')','') as      Phone

Answer (score 1):

// try this, in this case it allows you to replace for anything you need it to be.

```
    StringVar phone:= {yourTable.field};
    phone:= Replace(phone,"(","*");
    mid(phone, 1);
    replace(mid(phone, 1),")", "* ");
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS...

RIGHT CLICK ON PHONE NUMBER FIELD THEN SELECT FORMAT FIELD
FROM FORMAT FIELD SELECT COMMON TAB. UNDER DISPLAY STRING CLICK X-2 BOX
THEN WITE FORMULA -> PICTURE({YOURTABLE.FIELD), "(XXX) XXX-XXXX")

HOPE THIS HELPS!

Comment: There's no need to SHOUT.  Try using lower-case once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers can "be messed up" then you might want to consider sanitizing the entire string (also for those curious how to accomplish this in CR):

```
local stringvar phonenum := {table.phone_field};
local stringvar out := "";
local numbervar i;
for i:=1 to length(phonenum) do
  (
    if isnumeric(phonenum[i]) then //iterate over the characters in the string...
       out:=out + phonenum[i]; //...and toss out those which are non-numeric
  );

if length(out)<>10 then "Handle the error condition" else picture(out,"(xxx) xxx-xxxx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom function to 'supplement' the Replace() function:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// ReplaceEx()
// Author:      Craig Buchanan
// Purpose:     Support an array of find tokens
// Parameters:  text - the string being searched
//              find - an array of characters to be found
//              replacement - value to substitute
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
Function (Stringvar text, Stringvar Array find, Stringvar replacement)

    local numbervar i;

    For i:=1 To Ubound(find) do (

        text:=Replace(text, find[i], replacement)

    );

    text;
```

Use custom function in a formula field:

```
// returns {612) 555-1212
Picture(ReplaceEx("612-555-1212", ["(",")","-"], ""), "(xxx) xxx-xxxx")
```